# Why does CreateAcceleratorTable() not work without FVIRTKEY?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to create an accelerator for CTRL+A. I noticed that it doesn't work when you leave out FVIRTKEY, i.e. the following code snippet doesn't work:

```
a.fVirt = FCONTROL;
a.key = 'A';
a.cmd = IDM_ADD;
```

(just for completeness' sake: using 'a' instead of 'A' doesn't work either)

This, however, works fine:

```
a.fVirt = FCONTROL|FVIRTKEY;
a.key = 'A';
a.cmd = IDM_ADD;
```

Can somebody explain this behaviour? MSDN says that if FVIRTKEY isn't set, "key" is interpreted as a character code which I presume to be ASCII. But it doesn't work which leaves me somewhat puzzled.

Thanks!

Comment: To get a capital A, you'd have to press Shift + A.  Which of course conflicts with your FCONTROL option.  Ctrl + A generates a character with ASCII code 0x01.  Keep in mind that you are doing something that nobody ever does, using a [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is boilerplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system translates certain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key combinations into ASCII control codes. The combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is translated to the ASCII ctrl-A (SOH) character (ASCII value 0x01). This is the reason why your first snippet does not expose the desired behavior: It requires input that is impossible to enter. This is documented under [Keyboard Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153546.aspx) in the MSDN.

Also note that not providing the `FVIRTKEY` flag makes the specified `key` case-sensitive, i.e. `'a'` and `'A'` map to different input. It is usually desirable to use virtual key codes, to provide a consistent keyboard UI. The implications are explained under [About Keyboard Accelerators - Accelerator Keystroke Assignments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646335.aspx#_win32_Accelerator_Keystroke_Assignments).